# What is equivalent of apt-get or yum in any yocto system?

Tags: yocto, yum, apt

I want to know which package manager like `yum` and `apt-get` works for Yocto system?

Also, is there any way to get `yum` and/or `apt-get` to work for package installation on yocto.

Comment: There's an entire section in the manual on runtime package management, outlining your options: https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#using-runtime-package-management. Did you read that? Do you have any specific questions?

Answer (score 6):

There is no equivalent in most cases, because per default you do not have any package management on the running system. Everything is packaged and installed during image creation.

That said, you can enable the package management `IMAGE_FEATURE`, but theres more to it as you also have to provide the package feeds that match your build and so on. There is some pretty good documentation here: [Package Managers in Yocto](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/package-manager-white-paper.pdf), but its still quite a bit of work.

If your use case absolutely mandates per-device package management during runtime, or even requires using specific repositories, you might be better off choosing a different distribution/building mechanism than Yocto.

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 3):

Take deb for example

add the following to conf/local.conf:

```
PACKAGE_CLASSES = "package_deb"
PACKAGE_FEED_URIS = "http://some_domain_or_ip:5678"
EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES += " package-management "
```

Then build the image.

Then run the image. In the target system, you can check whether the support for package management has been added:

```sh
which apt-get
ls -lh /etc/apt/sources.list
```

You'll probably need to set up the package server as well. Then after, you can install precompiled package as you would do in debian/ubuntu:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install some_package
```

see the [step by step examples](https://imxdev.gitlab.io/tutorial/How_to_apt-get_to_the_Yocto_Project_image/):